# Website exit intend detection technology patent

Tags: websites, internet, programming, us20140222502

I am making a website code that will display popup when user tries to leave website. Javascript code is used for that. A solution how to detect mouse leave window was published 5 years ago inside Stackoverflow ([link to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923299/how-can-i-detect-when-the-mouse-leaves-the-window)). The solution doesn't mention to show popup, it is just how to detect user leaving the site.

What worries me is Bounce Exchange company has a patent to display popup when user leaves window.

> Use action in the form of movement of a tracking device on a webpage, represented by cursor gestures on the webpage, is used to detect it a user intends to leave the webpage. Upon detection of an intent to leave the webpage, an advertisement may be displayed to a use.

[Patent url](http://www.google.com/patents/US20140222502)

Do you think I can use the solution mentioned inside Stackoverflow for displaying popup? The solution also uses cursor gestures to track exit intend. But it doesn't say anything about displaying popup. So that worries me because Bounce Exchange claims to have a patent of using similar solution to display popup.

Answer (score 1):

This document is *not* a granted patent. It is the publication of a patent application. If it is issued as a patent in the future the key will be the wording of the claims, not the abstract or other parts of the document.